# How can I use audio files in next.js13?

Tags: next.js13

I am trying to use audio files in Next.js 13, "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)" This error occurs.
What should I do?

- SoundComponent

```
"use client";

import tickSound from "../../sounds/tick1.wav";

export default function Sound() {
  const tick = new Audio(tickSound);
  const metronomeSoundHandler = () => {
    tick.play();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={metronomeSoundHandler}>Play</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

- Next.config.js

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

[image]

I want to use audio file

Answer (score 0):

if your are using ts with nextjs

add the type declaration in a file named as sound.d.ts[or use your name]

declare module '*.mp3' {
const content: string
export default content
}
need a new definition in tsConfig file if you don't already have one.

In the hook, make sure you inline the path to the sound file instead of using an import statement:
import useSound from "use-sound";
const [playsound] = useSound('/sounds/my-recod.mp3')

[image: defination]

[image: sound.d.ts]